# Popping sound with SourceDataLine audio

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a class that plays a pure sine tone at any frequency and length desired and it working as expected -- except for a slight popping sound from the speakers that occurs at the beginning and end of every tone. This was initially a music theory experiment, but I have recently been using it to play bits of songs and might even try to bind frequencies to the keyboard and make it an instrument. The problem is that the pops occur between each tone, making the phrase sound wrong.

Here is the source:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*; 

public class Tone {
    public static float SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;

    public static void sound(double frequency, int duration, double velocity)
    throws LineUnavailableException {
        if (frequency < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Frequency too low: " + frequency + " is less than 0.0");

        if (duration <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration too low: " + duration + " is less than or equal to 0");

        if (velocity > 1.0 || velocity < 0.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Velocity out of range: " + velocity + " is less than 0.0 or greater than 1.0");

        byte[] wave = new byte[(int)SAMPLE_RATE * duration / 1000];

        for (int i=0; i<wave.length; i++) {
            double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / frequency) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            wave[i] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * velocity);
        }

        // Shape Waveform
        for (int i=0; i < SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0 && i < wave.length / 2; i++) {
            wave[i] = (byte)(wave[i] * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0));
            wave[wave.length-1-i] =
            (byte)(wave[wave.length-1-i] * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0));
        }

        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, false);
        SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        sdl.open(af);
        sdl.start();
        sdl.write(wave, 0, wave.length);
        sdl.drain();
        sdl.close();
    }

    public static double HALF_STEP = 1.0595;
    public static double WHOLE_STEP = HALF_STEP * HALF_STEP;
    public static double OCTAL_STEP = 2;

    public static double oct(double octive){
        if (octive < 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Octive too low: " + octive + " is less than 3.0");

        octive = octive - 2;
        octive = Math.pow(OCTAL_STEP, octive);

        return octive;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
    LineUnavailableException {
        // Preset Frequencies in Concert Notation starting from Octive 3
        double rest = 0;
        double c = 130.81;
        double c$ = c * HALF_STEP;
        double d = c$ * HALF_STEP;
        double d$ = d * HALF_STEP;
        double e = d$ * HALF_STEP;
        double f = e * HALF_STEP;
        double f$ = f * HALF_STEP;
        double g = f$ * HALF_STEP;
        double g$ = g * HALF_STEP;
        double a = g$ * HALF_STEP;
        double a$ = a * HALF_STEP;
        double b = a$ * HALF_STEP;

        // Default BPM
        int bpm = 128;

        // Note Duration Calculations
        int whole = 1000 * 240 / bpm;
        int half = 1000 * 120 / bpm;
        int quarter = 1000 * 60 / bpm;
        int eighth = 1000 * 30 / bpm;
        int sixteenth = 1000 * 15 / bpm;
        int thirtysecond = 1000 * 7 / bpm;

        // Test Tones
        Tone.sound (c * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (c$ * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (d * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (d$ * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (e * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (f * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (f$ * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (g * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (g$ * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (a * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (a$ * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (b * oct(3), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (c * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (c$ * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (d * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (d$ * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (e * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (f * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound (f$ * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);

        // John Cena, Doot Doot Doot
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(a * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(f * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(rest, thirtysecond, 0);
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth + half, 0.5);

        Tone.sound(rest, eighth, 0);
        Tone.sound(a$ * oct(4), eighth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(a * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(f * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(rest, thirtysecond, 0);
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth + half, 0.5);

        Tone.sound(rest, eighth, 0);
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(a * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(f * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(rest, thirtysecond, 0);
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth + half, 0.5);

        Tone.sound(rest, eighth, 0);
        Tone.sound(a$ * oct(4), eighth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(a * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(f * oct(4), sixteenth, 0.5);
        Tone.sound(rest, thirtysecond, 0);
        Tone.sound(g * oct(4), eighth + half, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Note: I am really new to java, and I am sure that my style is all kinds of messed up. Feel free to critique or change that while you're here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are hearing is the result of the discontinuity from 0 volume to full volume of the frequency. To eliminate the pop, you need to gradually start or stop the tone.

A simple way to do this would be to create a volume factor and increment it from 0 to 1 over the course of the first and/or last sound frames of your audio sample. You'll have to experiment to determine the exact number of frames needed. I'd try something like 64 frames. You can always make this figure larger if the pops are still present, and smaller may also work just fine.

Maybe something like this:

```
int rampFrames = 64;

for (int i = 0; i < rampFrames; i++)
{
     wave[i] *= i/(float)rampFrames;
}
```

Something similar can be done for the releases. AND, something similar will probably have to be done whenever you change the volume of a tone if there is a pop when you transition.

Perceived volume doesn't strictly match the linear increments used above, but the progress is so quick that this most likely won't be an issue.